# Install Japanese input method on exGENT

Tags: gentoo, portage

I installed exGENT Xfce in VirtualBox.
I'd like to install fcitx, fcitx-configtool, fcitx-anthy.
An error message will be issued as below.

```
!!! /etc/portage/make.profile is not a symlink and will probably prevent most message.
It should point into a profile within /usr/portage/profiles/
(It can safely ignore this message when syncing. It's harmless.)

!!! You current profile is invald. If you have just changed your profile.
!!! configuration, you shuld revent back to the previous configration.
!!! All owed action are limited to --help, --info, --seach, --sync, and --version.
```

What kind of operation procedure can be used to install?
Thank you.

Comment: this error only happens when you install the listed packages?

Comment: Thanks a lot hyph.
This error message was displayed when trying to install something that is not listed packages.

Comment: how did you solve it?